# How to Fetch SIngle Pull Request From Github API programmatically

Tags: github, pull-request

I created an ASP.NET console application and want to get data from a single pull request in GitHub through the API, but I couldn't get enough information on this page:

https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/

So my question is:
1.Any sample?
2.What's the endpoint of the API?
3.If everyone can access to this GitHub pr link, do I still need authentication?

Thank you so much guys!!!